# Prevent the text going out of the container if it's over 90% width

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I want to get the progress text to be inside the container `progressish`, even if the width is for an example 100%. As it is right now, the text is fixed to the right of the container, as seen in the first image below.

[image]

When the width of the progress bar is for an example 40%, it looks like this (as expected):

[image]

But when the progress is either 90% or 100%, I want the text to stuck to the far right of the progress bar, like this:

[image]
[image]

```css
section#progressish {
  width: 300px;
}

div#text {}

div#text>div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: auto !important;
  width: 100px;
}

div#progressbar {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

div#progressbar>.progress[data="bar"] {
  background-color: #111111;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="progressish">
  <div id="text">
    <div>100% avklarat</div>
  </div>

  <div id="progressbar">
    <div class="progress" data="bar"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

How can I accomplish this? You can see the whole source code at jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a7buqqkk/.

Comment: @Jer: I don't want the text to be stuck to the right all the time. Please read my question once again.

Comment: i'm sorry, didn't understand your question that good haha! Forget what i've commented ;)

Comment: @Erik , check my answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the width of the scrollbar is fixed (300px), and the text's width (the text, not the element) is more or less fixed (about 85px - from 1% to 100%), set the text as an absolutely positioned pseudo element child of the `.progress`, and set it's `width` and `max-width`:

```
width: calc(100% + 100px);
max-width: 300px;
```

If you align the text to the right, it will appear after the bar, until `max-width` is reached.

```js
/** js to demonstrate changing values **/
var progressBar = document.querySelector('.progress');
function progress() {
  var minmax = [0, 100];
  var step = 1;
  
  const iterate = (current) => {
    progressBar.style.width = `${current}%`;
    progressBar.setAttribute('data-percentage', current);
    
    if(current !== minmax[1]) {
      setTimeout(() => iterate(current + step), 40);
    } else {
      minmax = minmax.reverse();
      step = -step;
      
      setTimeout(() => iterate(minmax[0]), 500);
    }
  }
  
  iterate(minmax[0]);
}

progress();
```

```css
section#progressish {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
}

div#progressbar {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

div#progressbar>.progress[data="bar"] {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #111111;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 0%;
}

.progress::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  width: calc(100% + 85px);
  max-width: 300px;
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
  content: attr(data-percentage)"% avklarat";
}
```

```html
<section id="progressish">
  <div id="progressbar">
    <div class="progress" data="bar" data-percentage></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: what is If text be `1% avklarat`?

Comment: @ehsan - This is exactly why I wrote - more or less fixed. I've added a demo of the animation with displaying the values.

Comment: Thanks,what is your idea about my answer? Your idea is for me important.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox for `#text > div` and pseudoelement with needed `width`. Also add `white-space: nowrap` for text to not wrap. Replaced `id`s with `class`es to show multiple progressbar values.

Demo:

```css
section.progressish {
  width: 300px;
}

div.text > div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: auto !important;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.text > div:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
}

div.progressbar {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

div.progressbar > .progress[data="bar"] {
  background-color: #111111;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.progressish:nth-child(1) .text > div:before,
.progressish:nth-child(1) .progress[data="bar"] {
  width: 20%;
}

.progressish:nth-child(2) .text > div:before,
.progressish:nth-child(2) .progress[data="bar"] {
  width: 40%;
}

.progressish:nth-child(3) .text > div:before,
.progressish:nth-child(3) .progress[data="bar"] {
  width: 60%;
}

.progressish:nth-child(3) .text > div:before,
.progressish:nth-child(3) .progress[data="bar"] {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<section class="progressish">
  <div class="text">
    <div>20% avklarat</div>
  </div>

  <div class="progressbar">
    <div class="progress" data="bar"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="progressish">
  <div class="text">
    <div>40% avklarat</div>
  </div>

  <div class="progressbar">
    <div class="progress" data="bar"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="progressish">
  <div class="text">
    <div>60% avklarat</div>
  </div>

  <div class="progressbar">
    <div class="progress" data="bar"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="progressish">
  <div class="text">
    <div>80% avklarat</div>
  </div>

  <div class="progressbar">
    <div class="progress" data="bar"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="progressish">
  <div class="text">
    <div>100% avklarat</div>
  </div>

  <div class="progressbar">
    <div class="progress" data="bar"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Showing with animation:

```css
section.progressish {
  width: 300px;
}

div.text > div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: auto !important;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.text > div:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0%;
}

div.progressbar {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

div.progressbar > .progress[data="bar"] {
  background-color: #111111;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 0%;
}

div.progressbar > .progress[data="bar"],
div.text > div:before {
  animation: 4s linear 0s infinite alternate progress;
}

@keyframes progress { from { width: 0 } to { width: 100%; }  }
```

```html
<section class="progressish">
  <div class="text">
    <div>100% avklarat</div>
  </div>

  <div class="progressbar">
    <div class="progress" data="bar"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

*In other answers,if change `width` on `section` element, code dont work well.but my answer ,not depend on `width of section`.*

**A) rectangle :**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var per;
    var ft = false;
    var totalWid = $('section').width();
    var spanWid = $('.txt').width();
    var bor = Math.floor(((totalWid - spanWid)/totalWid)*100) - 2;
    setInterval(function(){
        per = Math.round($('.progChild').width()/totalWid*100);
        $('.txt').html(per + '% Progress');
        if(per > bor && !ft){
            $('.txt').addClass('rig').removeClass('arrow');
            ft = !ft;
        }
        else if(per <= bor && ft){
            $('.txt').addClass('arrow').removeClass('rig');
            ft = !ft;
        }
    },100);
})
```

```css
section {
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.progParent {
    width: inherit;
    background-color:#000; 
    padding: 1px;
    position: relative;
}

.progChild {
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    animation:mov 5s linear infinite alternate;
    width: 0%;
    float: left;
}

.progParent:after {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: block;
}

.txt {
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    margin-left: -5px;
    padding:0 2px; 
    font-weight: bold;
}

.arrow:before {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border:5px solid;
    border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.rig {
    right: 0;
}

@keyframes mov {
    from {width: 0}
    to {width: 100%;background-color: green}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div class="progParent">
        <div class="progChild"></div>
        <span class="txt arrow">0% Progress</span>
    </div>
</section>
```

**B) circle :**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var per;
    var ft = false;
    var totalWid = $('section').width();
    var spanWid = $('.txt').width();
    var bor = Math.floor(((totalWid - spanWid)/totalWid)*100);
    setInterval(function(){
        per = Math.round($('.progChild').width()/totalWid*100);
        $('.txt').html(per + '%');
        if(per > bor && !ft){
            $('.txt').addClass('rig').removeClass('arrow');
            ft = !ft;
        }
        else if(per <= bor && ft){
            $('.txt').addClass('arrow').removeClass('rig');
            ft = !ft;
        }
    },100);
})
```

```css
section {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 100px 0 0 50px;
}

.progParent {
    width: inherit;
    background-color:#000; 
    padding: 1px;
    position: relative;
}

.progChild {
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    animation:mov 5s linear infinite alternate;
    width: 0%;
    float: left;
}

.progParent:after {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: block;
}

.txt {
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #000;
    color: orange;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    margin-left: -25px;
    padding:0;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.arrow:before {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border:5px solid;
    border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
    bottom: -9px;
    left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}

.rig {
    right: 0;
}

@keyframes mov {
    from {width: 0}
    to {width: 100%;background-color: green}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<section>
    <div class="progParent">
        <div class="progChild"></div>
        <span class="txt arrow">0%</span>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Erik ,check my answer!

Comment: It looks good, but you should separate the update logic (changing classes) from the animation (setInterval), so you won't have to run a loop in the background waiting for the numbers to change.

Comment: @OriDrori , Thank you!

Comment: @ehsan: Both yours and Ori Drori's answers looks good :) Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just give the container for the text a max-width property, for me it works with 69%, but you can specify in px also.
check my codepen:         https://codepen.io/Juanito/pen/LjxKBa

```
    <section id="progressish">
  <div id="text">
    <div>100% avklarat</div>
  </div>

  <div id="progressbar">
    <div class="progress" data="bar"></div>
  </div>
</section>

section#progressish {
  width: 300px;


}

div#text {max-width:69%}

div#text>div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  width: auto !important;
  width: 100px;

}

div#progressbar {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

div#progressbar>.progress[data="bar"] {
  background-color: #111111;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 60%;

}
```